# How should I pass read only vectors in functions in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

How should I pass read only vectors in functions in C++?

One way to do it is the usual way as const&

```
const vector<string>& input
```

but I was wondering maybe I should do it this way instead:

```
const vector<const string&>& input
```

I am not sure which one is better. Basically I want to pass
a vector only for reading purposes, and I want to do it efficiently,
and avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector of references is not possible in C++ and wont compile at all (as a reference may be implemented without storage).

Besides that even if it would be possible you cant simply convert a `std::vector<T>` to a `std::vector<T&>` or `std::vector<T*>` (which is possible).

Now asides from the techinally aspects: There is no need for this. It would actually create more overhead. If your passing a reference to your vector, its data is completely left untouched. The only operation done is the `PUSH` of the address of the vector onto the stack.

So go with your first solution